# Chrome and Firefox JavaScript execution caching behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, caching

I am working on a web application that involves doing a some computation with JavaScript. In a benchmark test, I found Chrome is significantly faster than Firefox in term of execution time. When I run with the built in performance analysis tool in both browsers, I found that Firefox spent a lot of time on this function whereas Chrome does not.

```js
// compute n choose k
function choose(n, k) {
  k = Math.min(n - k, k);
  let res = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    res *= n - k + i;
    res /= i;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Given that my application will invoke this function in the order of magnitude of `10^7` times each with `n <= 40` and `k <= 10` during the benchmark, I suspect that Chrome's JavaScript engine will cache the result of this function (since it's deterministic and has no side effect) whereas Firefox does not. However, I am not familiar enough with the internals of those 2 JavaScript engine to be sure. It's appreciated if someone can provide more detailed explanation.

In addition, how should I change my code or browser settings to make it run faster on Firefox?

Comment: You could memoize it and run it in a separate thread via web workers.

Comment: I stumbled on a similar issue while writing front-end code. An event handler that does DOM bounding client rect readings of an element's position uses coordinates that reflect the original position of the element, instead of the last coordinates, if that element was moved in the meantime. It seems that browsers do ahead-of-time evaluations inside functions and keep those in a cache anticipating that it will be quickly used by a function call.

Comment: I am interested in hearing more people talk about this but I can't find much. There's not much talk about how browsers internally cache things inside functions. Maybe people working on Chrome/Firefox could throw some light on this.